# Eclipse VS firemonkey VS qt для создания программы, работающей с фотографией

Tags: android, eclipse, radstudio, qt

Без знаний джавы, что выбрать, куда копать? В основном для создании программы, работающей с фотографией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробовал в Delphi - Приложения громоздкие и долго грузятся (даже HelloWorld получается 20mb и грузит около 5 сек)
Java учить придется, он не сложный.... уроки по андроиду мне тут понравились -> http://startandroid.ru

Comment: вот вот, неделю как начал..спасибо.

Comment: Я начал обучение именно оттуда ) 
К 20-му уроку представлял уже синтаксиси JAVA, 
после 40 урока стал писать сам, отыскивая инфу уже в гугле )

Answer (score 2):

[Думаю вот сюда.](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) Там так же есть и примеры.